# An interesting integral with a lot of well-known functions

Tags: integration, logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

Today I was surfing through YouTube and I cam across this **unique and interesting** integral on BriTheMathGuy YouTube channel. The integral is as follows :

$\text{Q. Compute}$ $$\int_{0}^{1} (x^x)^{(x^x)^{(x^x)^{\cdots}}}dx$$ I didn't watch the full video and tried to attempt it first on my own.

**My Attempt :**
$$\text{Let}\space t = (x^x)^{(x^x)^{(x^x)^{\cdots}}}$$
$$\implies t = (x^x)^t$$ Taking the natural log of both sides, we get :
$$\ln(t) = t\ln(x^x)$$ Transposing the $t$ to the LHS, we get :
$$\ln(t)\space e^{-\ln(t)} = \ln(x^x) \tag{t = exp(ln(t))}$$
Now, after giving it some thoughts, I found out that the LHS is very close to the Lambert Function . So, I took the negative of both the sides and got :
$$-\ln(t)\space e^{-\ln(t)} = -\ln(x^x)$$ Then taking the Lambert Function of both sides, we get :
$$-\ln(t) = W(-\ln(x^x))$$ After all the necessary transposition, we get that :
$$t = e^{-W(-\ln(x^x))}$$ After this I am completely lost and don't know what to do next. I watched the video but did not understand the steps mentioned. It would be a great help if anybody can help me with it. Any hint/answer is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Man, why are there so many function of $x^{x^{\dots}}$ reappearing one place another on MSE recently.?

Comment: @GEdgar Thank You, That makes it really easy to compute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not an asnwer. Just for the fun (I cannot watch the video)*

I think that a series solution could be a way to go.

For level $n$, we have
$$f_n=1+t+\frac {2n-1} {2!}  t^2+\frac { 3n^2-2} {3!}  t^3+\frac {4 n^3+12 n^2-24 n+9} {4!} t^4+$$ $$\frac {5 n^4+60 n^3-120 n^2+60 n-4} {5!} t^5+\frac {6 n^5+210 n^4-360 n^3+240 n-95} {6!} t^6+$$ $$\frac {7 n^6+630 n^5-420 n^4-2520 n^3+4200 n^2-2310 n+414} {7!} t^7+\cdots$$ with $t=x\log(x)$ and
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \big[x \log(x)\big]^n\,dx=(-1)^n (n+1)^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (n+1)$$

Try to find the patterns for the next terms (I suppose that you will need many more).

In any manner, the result is going asymptotically to $1^-$ (quite slow convergence)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 0.7834282752 \\
 2 & 0.8319574446 \\
 3 & 0.8702455444 \\
 4 & 0.8999112011 \\
 5 & 0.9226399809 \\
 6 & 0.9399475265 \\
 7 & 0.9530953090 \\
 8 & 0.9630868363 \\
 9 & 0.9706985544 \\
 10 & 0.9765210224 \\
 20 & 0.9955618388 \\
 30 & 0.9983126577 \\
 40 & 0.9991074389 \\
 50 & 0.9994485136 \\
 60 & 0.9996236687 \\
 70 & 0.9997327583 \\
 80 & 0.9998003736 \\
 90 & 0.9998441300 \\
 100 & 0.9998503081
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Writing
$$f_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{P_k(n)} {k!} \big[x \log(x) \big]^k$$
$$\int_0^1 f_n\,dx=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{P_k(n)}{(k+1)^{k+1} }$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am so sorry to know about your blindness.